# how to insert values from list/menu into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert the grades into the mysql database. my list/menu as follow

```
  <select name="grade" size="1" id="select">
        <option value="" selected="selected">--- Select ---</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="A-">A-</option>
        <option value="B+">B+</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="B-">B-</option>
  </select>
```

i used this code but grades didn't insert in the database and error message appeared

```
     <?php
$grade = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['grade']);

$sql3 = "INSERT  (enrollment_id, stud_id, code, grade, date_enrolled) VALUES ('','','','$_POST[grade]','')";
$result = mysql_query($sql3);

if(mysql_query($sql3))
{
    echo 'User information saved successfully.';
}else
{
    echo 'Error: We encountered an error while inserting the new record.';
}
mysql_close($con_mark_entry);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I think this kind of questions should not be downvoted. Without looking at the quality of coding, the user has tried something and has posted his code.

Answer (score 0):

Like MySQL would say, "you have an error in your syntax". I think this should work:

`$sql3 = "INSERT INTO your_sql_table (enrollment_id, stud_id, code, grade, date_enrolled) VALUES ('','','','$grade','')";`

I would suggest adding `echo mysql_error()` after your "We encountered an error" message for debugging purposes.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and and this message appeares'User information saved successfully.' but the value didn't save in the database

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. It should be 
`INSERT INTO Table Name (COL1, COL2) VALUES (VAL1,VAL2)`